# Rest API error " "resources": "Magento_CatalogInventory::cataloginventory""

Tags: magento2, rest-api, quantity

I am trying to fetch the quantity with

> https:mydomain.com/index.php/rest/V1/stockItems/24-MB01

I got the following error :

"message": "The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.",
    "parameters": {
        "resources": "Magento_CatalogInventory::cataloginventory"
    },

my Token is correct because I got the product list with the same token.
I have to select the checkbox related stock but I don't know which is missing to select the checkbox in the API tab. The following checkbox was selected.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

select the **Inventory Section** checkbook for getting the quantity form **https:mydomain.com/index.php/rest/V1/stockItems/24-MB01** API

Comment: did you get a solution for this? i am also facing this issue

Comment: yes you can try that.